# Compare functions to find which one is more sensitive to change

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials

Suppose we have different polynomial functions : $P_1(x)=a_1x^{n}+a_2x^{n-1}+...+a_n$ ,
$P_2(x)=b_1x^{n}+b_2x^{n-1}+...+b_n$ and $P_3(x)=c_1x^{n}+c_2x^{n-1}+...+c_n$.. To find the rate of change in these functions I should differentiate them. But I want to know which one is more sensitive to change. Or compare them according to  "speed of the rate of change". How can I do it? If it possible to compare according to rate of change is there any difference between generally and certain interval?

Comment: The rate of change depends on the location.

Comment: Could you suggest any supplementary material about it?